# Text Rendered in the image is very small in Java ..Not sure why

Tags: java, awt

Below is my source code

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class InternetSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Taj_Mahal_in_India_-
    _Kristian_Bertel.jpg"));
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 32);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString("Welcome To Taj Mahal!", 100, 100);
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("d:\\Taj_Mahal.png"));
  }
}
```

Expected:

- Font size should be 32 as set in the code

Actual:

- Font size is small

Question:

1. The font size is defined as 32 but why it is showing small?
2. Do we need to set the font according to some algorithm or strateggy?
3. What is the best practice to set the font

The Java specification on graphics doesn't say much about it. Not sure where to refer for the detailed examples to make it work as expected.

Even in full screen it shows as below

[image]

Word in font size 32

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248611/discussion-on-question-by-testjava-dev-text-rendered-in-the-image-is-very-small).

Answer (score 0):

I'll post something that might help because it's not 100% clear what is wrong with what you've received so far. The following will size the caption to a fraction of the entire image width (currently a quarter). Obviously you need to remove the 'magic numbers' and tweak according to your requirements and remove any hard-coding remaining. I'll say right off that it's not really the 'proper' way of doing it, since the correct transformation should be applied without looping, probably via something like an `AffineTransform`  with the correct geometry from the start to derive the font.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class InternetSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 1);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        String caption = "Welcome To Taj Mahal!";
        getFontSizedForCaption(image, caption, font, g);
        g.drawString(caption, 100, 100);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Taj_Mahal.png"));
    }

    static Font getFontSizedForCaption(BufferedImage img, String caption, Font startFont, Graphics g) {
        Font derivedFont = startFont;
        int imgWidth = img.getWidth();
        float fontSize = 1.0f;
        double captionWidth = 0.0;
        // Fraction of the image width that the caption width takes up
        while (captionWidth < (imgWidth / 4)) {
            derivedFont = derivedFont.deriveFont(fontSize);
            g.setFont(derivedFont);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            Rectangle2D captionRect = fm.getStringBounds(caption, g);
            captionWidth = captionRect.getWidth();
            //System.out.printf("Width now %.2f%n", captionRect.getWidth());
            fontSize += 5.0f;
        }
        return derivedFont;
    }
}
```

Comment: @goose - Is the above code to change the font point according to pixels ?

Comment: According to proportions. The units of measurement aren't relevant

Comment: I didn't understand. can you please explain...

Comment: The comment *// Fraction of the image width that the caption width takes up* explains how it works

Comment: font size += 0.5 line couldn't understand. why we need this

Comment: To grow the size of the font

Comment: why it is 0.5 only? what is the context. can you pls explain

Answer (score 0):

Your font is rendered based on the image quality, a good way in my opinion is to multiply the font with a factor to resize it based on the image size, the following function might help you

```
/**
 * compute a factor for different image qualities
 *
 * @param image the image to compute the factor
 * @param coefficient to scale the factor
 * @return
 */
private static double getImageFactor(BufferedImage image, int coefficient) {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double screenSizeWidth = screenSize.getWidth();
    double screenSizeHeight = screenSize.getHeight();
    double screenHypotenuse = Math.sqrt(screenSizeWidth * screenSizeWidth + screenSizeHeight * screenSizeHeight);

    Rectangle bounds = image.getData().getBounds();
    double imageWidth = bounds.getWidth();
    double imageHeight = bounds.getHeight();
    double imageHypotenuse = Math.sqrt(imageWidth * imageWidth + imageHeight * imageHeight);

    return imageHypotenuse * coefficient / (screenHypotenuse + screenHypotenuse);
}
```

and in order to use it you can call it with a coefficient which might be decided by you

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, (int) (32 * getImageFactor(image, 2)));
```

note that there might be a more delicate way to compute the factor but in this case it might suffice.

Comment: Is the above code to change the font point according to pixels ?

Comment: @testjavadev yes, both `getScreenSize` and `getBounds` return values are in pixels.

Comment: You are using toolkit screensize which will take server screeen size. It would be wrong since the web app will be hosted in any server where monitor sizes would differ